# The preposition "to" after the verb "write"

Tags: objects, direct-objects, ditransitive-verbs

Raymond Murphy says to use the preposition "to" after the verb "write" (write a letter to somebody), but the famous song contains following words:

I'm gonna sit right down and write myself a letter.

How can you explain that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answers you've been given here are good, but I would also caution: Do not look at popular songs for examples of good grammar and usage.  They're written to sound good, not to be grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"to write"** is used here as a **transitive verb** and *"a transitive verb can also have an indirect object, which is a noun, pronoun, or noun phrase that comes before a direct object and indicates the person or thing that receives what is being given or done. Many common verbs can be used with both direct and indirect objects."* [[**Source**]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transitive)

- Send *me* **a letter**
- Write *me* **a poem**
- Give *him* **the towel**

*The indirect object in *Italics* and the direct object in **Bold**

Answer (score 4):

Ditransitive verbs (i.e verbs that can take two objects) have two patterns : Prepositional pattern and dative-movement pattern.

Okay let me explain

Prepositional pattern is when the direct object follows the verb and the indirect object is moved into a prepositional phrase (that is usually preceded by *for* or *to*). For example,

- I write a letter to myself (The direct object is "a letter" and is followed by a prepositional phrase).

Dative-movement pattern is when the verb is followed by an indirect object and direct object consecutively.

- I write myself a letter (The indirect object is "myself" and the direct object is "a letter").

Comment: +1 But I think most contemporary grammarians would distinguish between the syntactic construction and the semantic role and say that *myself* is the semantic Recipient in both constructions but it's only an "indirect object" when it's in object position, not when it's the oblique in the prepositional construction.